SDKMAN gradle installation, where is the Gradle home ~/.gradle folder with init.gradle?
In the past I have installed Gradle "manually" with the vanilla installation process.
Now I want to use Gradle via SDKMAN. After installing, I can run Gradle commands and I see the Gradle installation within the /candidates SDKMAN folder.
But I don't see the "Gradle home" folder that for the typical installation is ~/.gradle on MacOS. I'm most interested in this folder because it is previously where I kept my init.gradle script with some global configuration.
I checked the SDKMAN and relevant Gradle docs but they don't make any mention of how to use SDKMAN with Gradle beyond installing it.
Where is this directory/file for SDKMAN Gradle installations?
Thanks

sdkman uses everything contained, so it should probably be inside the candidates/gradle folder? Have you checked inside it?

@JorgeCampos you're right, I thought I checked this but it turns out the structure is a bit different. in /candidates/gradle, there's an init.d folder that contains a readme.txt which explains that .gradle files can be placed there, that's what I was looking for.

Awesome, glad to be of help

Please post and accept an Answer to your own Question, for posterity.
